# In WinRT, static field not initialized at all

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have the code like this

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private static int staticField = 10;
}
```

The code never gets executed and staticField has default value 0. 
Also the code causes MVVMlight's SimpleIoc to throw an exception with code like this:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SomeClass>();
```

Above code causes MVVMLight to throw an exception saying

```
 Cannot build instance: Multiple constructors found but none marked with PreferredConstructor.
```

This very bizarre. 
I'm using Win8 RTM x64 + VS2012 Express for Windows 8.

Comment: The exception has nothing to do with the static field. The exception states that you have multiple ctors defined on SomeClass and SimpleIoc does know which one to use to create an instance.

Comment: no, i have no constructor whatsoever. And after I remove the static field, it won't throw exception anymore. You can test it for yourself

Comment: Can you show the code that accesses this static field with the wrong value? it is normal for the static constructor to not be invoked until it is definitely needed (the exact when is very complicated).

Comment: It's as simple as this

    int y = staticField;

And I don't have a static constructor, so I don't know what you mean. I think this is a bug in winrt, cause in regular .net this workds fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is definitely a bug in SimpleIoc of MVVMLight. I have tried it with LinqPad and the problem is when you add a static field to the class an static ctor is added by the field initializer.

The result is that the class SomeClass has two ctors for SimpleIoc, what results in the exception you described.

A Workaround would be to add a default constructor to the class and decorate it with the `PreferredConstructorAttribute` but this will result in a dependency to SimpleIoc.

Other solution would be to change your static field to a constant value.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private const int staticField = 10;
}
```

or to use an overload of the Register method to provide a factory method for instance creation.

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SomeClass>(() => new SomeClass())
```

I have submitted a [bug report](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7595) on the MVVM Light project on CodePlex

**LinqPad (Test code):**

```
    void Main()
{
    var x = GetConstructorInfo(typeof(SomeClass));

    x.Dump();
    x.IsStatic.Dump();
}


public class PreferredConstructorAttribute : Attribute{

}
public class SomeClass{
  private static int staticField = 10;

}

private ConstructorInfo GetConstructorInfo(Type serviceType)
        {
            Type resolveTo = serviceType;


//#if NETFX_CORE
            var constructorInfos = resolveTo.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredConstructors.ToArray();
            constructorInfos.Dump();
//#else
//          var constructorInfos = resolveTo.GetConstructors();
//constructorInfos.Dump();
//#endif

            if (constructorInfos.Length > 1)
            {
                var preferredConstructorInfos
                    = from t in constructorInfos
//#if NETFX_CORE
                       let attribute = t.GetCustomAttribute(typeof (PreferredConstructorAttribute))
//#else
//                     let attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(t, typeof(PreferredConstructorAttribute))
//#endif
                       where attribute != null
                       select t;

preferredConstructorInfos.Dump();

var preferredConstructorInfo = preferredConstructorInfos.FirstOrDefault ( );
                if (preferredConstructorInfo == null)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(
                        "Cannot build instance: Multiple constructors found but none marked with PreferredConstructor.");
                }

                return preferredConstructorInfo;
            }

            return constructorInfos[0];
        }
// Define other methods and classes here
```

The problem is the line

```
var constructorInfos = resolveTo.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredConstructors.ToArray();
```

that returns an array with 2 ConstructorInfos both defined without the PreferredConstructorAttribute which results in the exception.

Comment: It is the *field initializer*, not the field, that causes the addition of the static constructor. Interesting that MVVMLight thinks it is an instance constructor, though

Comment: This workaround is fine but now that I don't need have constructor so I would have to add an empty ctor only to satisfy MVVMLight. I instead of using a factory to register the type like this

    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SomeClass>(() => new SomeClass());

Comment: @imgen. I have added your solution to my answer.

Comment: @Jehof, but what about the WinRT bug that the static field initialization is not executed